# Azure push notifications + .NET MVC - how to debug or resolve

Tags: asp.net-mvc, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

We are attempting to send push notifications via Azure Notification Hub and aren't able to send messages from Azure.
We've tried debugging but have been unable to figure out the error from the documentation.

How can we debug this further?  We've walked through MSDN's documentation in detail but haven't been able to come up with anything

Here's our process:

1. We have the certificate setup in our iphone app and in Azure Notification Hub
2. We create our hub connection via NotificationHubClient with the debug option enabled before any Azure calls

`NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_CONNECTION_STRING, NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_NAME, true)`

3. We register the device upon logging into the app (and we're updating the push id if it changes)

   `//simplified process showing a new registration only
   RegistrationDescription registration = 
   Hub.CreateAppleNativeRegistrationAsync(data.PushId, new List<string>() { "member:10" });
   registration.RegistrationId = Hub.CreateRegistrationIdAsync().Result;
   var result = Hub.CreateOrUpdateRegistrationAsync(registration).Result;`

   **Result**: We appear to get back a successful RegistrationDescription that shows our registration id, tags, device token (pushId), etag and registration id.  We do show successful registration operations in the Azure Monitor.

   **Note**: After registering the device, we don't see an increase in active devices or registrations in our Azure dashboard (0 Active Devices and 0 registrations in the dashboard)
4. We send a notification

   `// example apns: {"aps":{"alert":{"title":"TESTING","body":"Test notification"}},"MemberId":150888,"RelatedId":1,"NotificationType":2,"NotificationTypeId":2}
   var notification = Hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(apns.ToJson(), "member:10").Result;`

   **Result:** We normally receive a result similar to below, however a notification is not sent
   "Notification state: DetailedStateAvailable, success: 1, tracking id: xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx, notification id: {empty} Platform: apple, Device reg id: {removed for security}, Result: The Notification was successfully sent to the Push Notification System, PnsHandle: xxx"

**Other Notes**:  We do see several "Invalid Channel Errors", "APNS Bad Channel Error" and "APNS Expired Channel Errors" but cannot find the source.  We also see several Successful Notifications logged in Azure, but never receive the notification.

Answer (score 0):

The success states that you were able to request a send.
The Invalid Channel Errors and APNS Bad Channel Error indicate that you have an invalid device token. This typically happens because:

1. You have told NH you are using the APNS sandbox, but your app is getting tokens for APNS production.

OR

2. Reverse the states in #1 (NH thinks you have APNS production, your app is getting tokens for APNS sandbox)